# To prove union of connected sets is not connected.

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let V be span of $(1,1,1) $and $(0,1,1)$.Let $p=(0,0,1),q=(1,1,0),r=(1,0,1)$
Then prove that $ \Bbb R ^3-V \cup$ $\{tp+(1-t)r:t \in [0,1]\}$ is not connected.
 $V=\{a(1,1,1)+b(0,1,1):a,b \in \Bbb R\}$ ,Let $A=\Bbb R ^3-V$ and B=$\{tp+(1-t)r:t \in [0,1]\}$
We know that if A ,B are connected sets and $A \cup B$ is connected if $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.My doubt is how to prove intersection of A and B is empty?

Comment: $A$ is not connected. It the space without one plain, so two halves of the space, not connected.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{tp+(1-t)r\}$ has no mutual points  with $V$, because all points from $V$ have the form $(a,b,b)$ and all points from $\{tp+(1-t)r\}$ have the form $(1-t,0,1)$. So, $\{tp+(1-t)r\}$ lies in $A$ and then $A\cup \{tp+(1-t)r\}$ is simply $A$ and therefore not connected.

Comment: Why A is disconnected? How to prove that?

Comment: You take one point $x$ in $A$ and then You reflect it through the hyperplane $V$ to obtain the point $y$. $x$ and $y$ are both in $A$, but every path connecting them cross $V$.

Comment: Or another way: You write $V$ in the normal form: $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=\delta$. Then $A$ consists of two parts: $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z>\delta$ and $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z<\delta$. Both parts are open and disjunct, so $A$ is disconnected.